# Convert js array to another js array format

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my Js array

```
["field", "description", "example"]
```

I want to convert it into this

```
columnDefs: [
        {
          headerName: "Field",
          field: "field",
        },
        {
          headerName: "Description",
          field: "description",
        },
        {
          headerName: "Example",
          field: "example",
        }
      ],
```

Please help me out, how can I construct the above-mentioned Js array format.

Comment: Hint : you could use `.map()`

Comment: `my Json array` makes little sense.

Comment: Please consider using the term JS object instead of json.

Comment: Why not just have the desired data from the start? If you were ever to handle multiple languages or something with spaces, it is certainly easier to handle explicitly defining that data.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `map()`, `charAt()`, `toUpperCase()` and `slice()` like the following way:

```js
var arr = ["field", "description", "example"];
var columnDefs = arr.map((item, i) => ({headerName: item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1), field: item}));
console.log(columnDefs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Array.map`, you can map each item to the format in the output.

And you can make the each field to `capitalize` using `toUpperCase()` function.

```js
const arr = ["field", "description", "example"];
const output = {
  columnDefs: arr.map((item) => ({
    headerName: `${item[0].toUpperCase()}${item.substring(1)}`,
    field: item
  }))
};

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.map(item => ({ headerName: item.toUpperCase(), field: item }))
```

This should do the work.

Comment: The `{}` should be wrapped in parenthesis, or else it is interpreted as the function body and not an object literal. Also seems like you need to capitalize `headerName`

Answer (score 0):

```
let columnDefs = []

array.map(item=>{
  let colunn = {
    'headerName': item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1),
    'field': item
  }
  columnDefs.push(column)
}
```

Comment: array.map will return a new array - there's no need to use the additional `columnDefs` variable. Take a look at Harsh Vats answer. you could 

`["field", "description", "example"].map(item=> (
  {
    headerName: item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1),
    field: item
  })
)
`

Comment: @RYFN True. Didn't realize that when I was writing the comment. A few extra lines can be removed and be made more performant. Thanks.